# How to detect a grainy or faded image?

Tags: computer-vision

I've seen questions about detecting blurry images, but what about faded/grainy images. I have a large dataset of scanned passport-style portrait photos, and a number of them are old, hence looking faded and grainy (i.e hard to recognize the person).

Image quality metrics like BRISQUE and blur detection [[link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/?submitted_comment=1#comment-523789)] didn't work so well and were inconsistent. The criteria for classification would be whether the photo was good enough for an average person to tell who the person was from the image.
So I tried face detection (HOG, etc), but it recognizes images where it's pretty much impossible to tell who the person is. 
Ideally I'm looking for suggestions that is somewhat lightweight. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First idea I would check is **image histograms**. It's especially
   straightforward in case of grayscale images. My *assumption* is
   that quality photos have intensity distribution close to normal,
   while grainy and faded photos do not. If histograms look similar
   across images (looks like you have enough examples to check) in one
   group it's easy to classify new image based on its histogram. You
   can also consider counting histogram of image center's. Just area
   containing eyes, nose and mouth. Low-quality images may loose this
   details.
2. Another idea is to apply **low-frequencies filter** on image to remove
   noise. Than count some metric based on some **edge detector** (Sobel,
   Laplace, Canny, etc.) or just try to find any edges except one
   around hair.
3. Another way is to **average good images and compare this sample with
   new ones**. Higher difference will mean that observed image is not
   typical portrait. Or try face-detection with cascade-based detector.

Or maybe some combination of this ideas will give a good result on your problem.
Sure it's possible to train a NN classifier, but I think it's possible to solve that specific problem without it.